# Reset identity field in sql by one error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, identity

How can I reset identity field in a table in database by '0' value?

I used of this script:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT({table name}, reseed, 0)
```

But this has a error by this message :

> Incorrect syntax near CHECKIDENT

What is CHECKIDENT?

Comment: To be sure, you did put a real table name where you have `{table name}`...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you're doing - but this works **perfectly** well for me:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('EMP', reseed, 0)
```

Results in:

> Checking identity information: current identity value '12', current
>   column value '0'.
>   DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error
>   messages, contact your system administrator.

You need to make sure to put your table name into single quotes: use `'EMP'` - not `EMP`

`CHECKIDENT` (from: check identity) is just the name of the command for the `DBCC` function in SQL Server (there are a lot more `DBCC.......` commands available)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ("DBO.TABLENAME",RESEED)
```